# Input string does not match a numerical range

Tags: ruby, gets

The below ruby code is not working as expected. It doesn't seem to recognise the `1..3` range and is only reading the `else` condition. If I gave a number instead of a range, it works though. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
print "Enter your cost: "
cost = gets.chomp
case cost
when 1..3 
 puts "inexpensive"
when 3..5 
 puts "affordable"
else puts "no comments"
end
```

Comment: `not working as expected` => What do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match a string against an integer range. That's not going to work. Make an integer.

```
cost = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: thank you very much it works! i've been struggling with it for a long time - i'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

The input you get from `gets` is always a string, so it will never match a number range. To convert it to an integer, do this:

```
cost = gets.to_i
```

You can directly put it in case statement like so

```
case gets.to_i
```

Comment: Thanks! I was guessing so. Is there a way I could convert that to integer? I tried the Integer(cost) method but doesn't work. Could I say -  when Integer[cost] 1..3

Comment: `Integer(cost)` should work as well as long as it does not include extra characters. `String#to_i` is more flexible and is suitable in this case.